# Michaelis-Menten rate law for enzyme which catalyzes two reactions: steady state?

Tags: kinetics, enzyme-kinetics

Suppose an enzyme $\ce{E}$ can catalyze two reactions:

\begin{align}
\ce{S1 + E &<=> S1E ->  P1 + E} \tag{R1} \\
\ce{S2 + E &<=> S2E ->  P2 + E} \tag{R2}
\end{align}

I want to derive a rate law. Can I assume that

\begin{align}
\frac{d[\ce{S1E}]}{dt} &= 0 \tag{1}\\
\frac{d[\ce{S2E}]}{dt} &= 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

like in the derivation of the [Michaelis-Menten rate law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics#Derivation)?

Comment: Why do you think this assumption might be different in the two reaction case versus the one reaction case? (Note that the steady-state approximation relies on particular conditions, and isn't necessarily universally valid.)

Comment: @R.M. 
I want the same conditions as given when the Michaelis Menten rate law is valid: high amount of substrate, only initial velocities etc.

The assumption in the one reaction case relies on "the concentration of the intermediate complex does not change on the time-scale of product formation " (citing wikipedia)
I do not know how to estimate if this still holds true for the two reactions case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In the **steady-state reaction**, the intermediate concentration [ES] is assumed to remain at a small constant value. So **in this case only if k2 >> k1** and similar for the second reaction. ES is now a reactive intermediate and there is no stable equilibrium between S, E and P.

\begin{align}
\frac{d[\ce{S1E}]}{dt} &= \ce{k1}[\ce{S1}][\ce{E}] - k_{-1} [\ce{S1E}] - \ce{k2}[\ce{S1E}] = 0\\
\end{align}

Therfore:

\begin{align}
[\ce{S1E}] &= \frac{\ce{k1}}{k_{-1}+\ce{k2}}[\ce{S1}][\ce{E}] = K_a[\ce{S1}][\ce{E}]
\\
\end{align}

Similarly for the second reaction:

\begin{align}
[\ce{S2E}] &= \frac{\ce{k3}}{k_{-3}+\ce{k4}}[\ce{S2}][\ce{E}] = K_b[\ce{S2}][\ce{E}]
\\
\end{align}

The enzyme E is involved in both reactions and its total concentration(bound and unbound) is constant. This total concentration of enzyme $[E]_{0}$ is equivalent to the concentration of the free enzyme before adding the substrates. The concentration of the free enzyme at a certain time t is [E]:

\begin{align}
[E]_{0} &= [E] + [\ce{S1E}] + [\ce{S2E}]
\\
\end{align}

if you substitute $[\ce{S1E}]$ and $[\ce{S2E}]$ with the previous expressions then:

\begin{align}
[E] &= \frac{[E]_{0}}{1 + k_{a}[\ce{S1}]+k_{b}[\ce{S2}]}
\\
\end{align}

Eventually:
\begin{align}
\frac{d[P_{1}]}{dt} = k_2[\ce{S1E}] = \ce{k2}(K_a[\ce{S1}][\ce{E}]) = K_p[\ce{S1}][\ce{E}] = K_p[\ce{S1}]\frac{[E]_{0}}{1 + k_{a}[\ce{S1}]+k_{b}[\ce{S2}]}
\\
\end{align}

and similarly for the rate of production of $P_2$